# How do I split a string between / and "+" based on an outgoing link click, when there are colons in the actual URL?

Tags: javascript, string

JS Beginner here. I need to return itemName from a URL string, however, there are colons in the URL itself. When I split using ("""), I get an error that this won't work.

I have gotten this far, but I don't know what to change in my function to get the desired result. See the examples below:

Below is the URL:

```
 "https://www.website.com/items/item-name-1"+"?date_1=2022-10-05&date_2=2022-10-07&amount=2"
```

Below you can see my code.

```
  
   if ({{Outgoing link}})
  var itemName= {{Click URL}};
      return itemName.split("/")[5].split(".")[0];
   
    
    console.log(extractSliceFromUrl(itemName))

   }
```

This is my expected result:

```
 "item-name-1"
```

This is the actual result I get:

```
 "item-name-1"+"?date_1=2022-10-05&date_2=2022-10-07&amount=2"
```

Comment: Is the URL itself quoted, or is that a JS string?

Comment: @EphellonGrey, the URL is quoted. The colons in the middle of the URL are no part of the quote. These are actually in the URL.

Comment: The question is still ambiguos - does the string contain four literal `"` marks or is intended to be evaluated before processing such that it contains no literal `"` characters?

Comment: @DavePritlove; the string consits of 2 sets of colons in the middle of the string itself. The outer (quoting) colons, are not part of the string.

Comment: Thanks. There are no colons present (a colon is `:`), so I presume you mean the internal *double quote* marks (`"`) are to remain but the outer ones are not. That string cannot be represented in that way without escaping the inner quote marks with a back slash `\"` or by using alternative quotes for the outer ones (such as single quotes `'` or back-ticks). If the part you need always begins with `item-name`, you might consider using `string.indexOf('item-name')` to begin a string `.slice` and finish it with the index of the end-border (which I think, but am still not sure, is `"+"?`)

Comment: @DavePritlove;

You are absolutely right! apologies (English is not my first language). Sadly, the string is always different, it's a variable that I called Item-name, but it can be something different everytime. It's just always in the same place. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @VictorNorbart no problem. Does the item always immediately follow `/items/` and end immediately before `"+"?` ?

Answer (score 2):

Would the following work?

It extracts whatever's between the **last `/`** and the **first `"+"`**.

```js
const url = "\"https://www.website.com/items/item-name-1\"+\"?date_1=2022-10-05&date_2=2022-10-07&amount=2\"";
console.log(url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, url.indexOf('"+"')));
```

Comment: Thank you @ccjmne , the URL is a variable on its own, so would I then change the constant to '''var: {{URL}}?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm going crazy but... I genuinely don't recognize that syntax: `var: {{ URL }}`. Are you sure it's plain JavaScript? Do you know whether you're using some sort of preprocessor? In any case, I believe that if you simply replace `url` in my example with `itemName` in your code sample, all should be well 

Comment: My apologies for the confusion (and the bad formatting in my comments), I am a total beginner/N00B, still learning. To explain what I mean, I have an example here where I am using {{outgoing link}}(the {{URL}} was meant to be a reference to a before-defined variable. I am working in Google Tag Manager, therefore it looks like that): 

`function extractSliceFromUrl() {
  
   if ({{Outgoing link}})
  var itemName= {{Click URL}};
console.log(url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, url.indexOf('"+"')));`

Comment: No worries! We all started clueless . You should try `var url = {{ Click URL }}; var itemName = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, url.indexOf('"+"'));`. I think the `itemName` variable should evaluate to `"item-name-1"` (in your example) after that.

Comment: this sounds and looks like what I'm looking for! I will test it and see how far I come! Thank you very much :)

Comment: You're very welcome! Don't hesitate to ask more if anything's unclear :) Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

I'd split by `?` first:

`const theURL = "https://www.website.com/items/item-name-1"+"?date_1=2022-10-05&date_2=2022-10-07&amount=2";`

`theURL.split("?")[0].split("/")[5].split(".")[0];`

Answer (score 0):

With the secondary result, you could just remove the ending using:

```js
'"item-name-1"+"?date_1=2022-10-05&date_2=2022-10-07&amount=2"'.replace(/("[^"]+?")\+/, '$1')
```

---

##### Explanation of `/("[^"]+?")\+/` (RegExp)

- `(...)` catch the pattern (becomes the `$1`)
- `[^"]` everything **not** `"`
- `+?` get the shortest result possible
- `\+` escape `+` (`+` is a special symbol, this will treat it as plain text)

Answer (score 0):

please is the working code.

```
let strUrl = "https://www.website.com/items/item-name-1"+"?date_1=2022-10-05&date_2=2022-10-07&amount=2";
let urlArray = strUrl.split("/");
let itemName = urlArray[4].split("?")[0];
console.log(itemName);
```